# How can I get width and height from an image before upload in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a code in Vuejs that it uploads a image but I need to check the width and height of that image I have my code like this:

This is my input **:**

```
<input ref="file" accept="image/png" type="file" class="form-control" v-on:change="onFileChange" required>
```

This is a method that I use to upload when select the image **:**

```
onFileChange(e){
  this.file = e.target.files[0];
  this.noFile = e.target.files.length;
},
```

This is my code to upload **:**

```
onSubmit(e) {
   this.loading = true; //the loading begin
   e.preventDefault();
   let currentObj = this;

   const config = {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
   }

   axios.post('/api/section/store?api_token='+App.apiToken, formData, config)
       .then(function (response) {
       currentObj.success = response.data.success;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    })

   formData.append('file', this.file);
}
```

So I wonder how can I retrieve the width and height? I have tried this:

```
onFileChange(e){
  this.file = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(this.file.width);
  this.noFile = e.target.files.length;
},
```

It says `undefined`, so how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

A File object doesn't have a width and height. You would need to create an image object.

```
async onFileChange(e) {
   this.file = e.target.files[0];
   this.noFile = e.target.files.length;
   const photoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
   const image = new Image();
   const imageDimensions = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      image.onload = () => {
        const dimensions = {
          height: image.height,
          width: image.width,
        };
        resolve(dimensions);
      };
     image.src = photoUrl;
    });
    console.log(imageDimensions);
}
```

Comment: It says Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: URL.createObjectUrl is not a function what could it be ?

Comment: URL.createObjectUrl is a default method as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL. I accidentally typed createObjectUrl instead of createObjectURL. See the edit for the correct code.